# How to identify properties of the zeroes of this polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

If $f_0(x)=1$, and $f_{n+1}=\frac{d}{dx}((x^2-1)f_n(x))$, prove that every $f_n$ has exactly $n$ distinct zeroes, all located in the interval $(-1,1)$. It's got me stumped, so any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: if $f_n$ has exactly $n$ distinct zeros inside $(-1,1)$, then $(x^2-1)f_n(x)$ has exactly $n+2$ distinct zeros inside $[-1,1]$. By [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), ....